# JwPlayer Gradle Sync Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jwplayer

i can not compile jwplayer in Android project, Android Studio v 3.0.1

`minSdkVersion 19`

`targetSdkVersion 26`

`compileSdkVersion 26`

> Build.gradle `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+'
compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+'
```

> Messages

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@flavorPublicDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+.

License Key Defined in Androidmanifest

it works on other projects created before

Gradle :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

repository :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

gradle task :

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+.
      > Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not HEAD 'http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Connect to 127.0.0.1:50077 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+.
      > Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
              > Connect to 127.0.0.1:50077 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+.
      > Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Connect to 127.0.0.1:50077 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
      > Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not HEAD 'http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Connect to 127.0.0.1:50077 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
      > Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml'.
              > Connect to 127.0.0.1:50077 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
      > Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Connect to 127.0.0.1:50077 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

How i can solve it ?

**build.gradle app :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.asemanltd.app.shabakema"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 5000
    versionName '0.5.0'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    /*flavorDimensions 'public'
    productFlavors {
    flavorPublic {
        dimension 'public'
        minSdkVersion 19
        applicationId 'com.asemanltd.app.shabakema'
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        versionCode 5000
        versionName '0.5.0'
    }
    }*/
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    // implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-laljyout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    // JW player
    compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+'
    compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+'
    // Material Dialog
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    // Glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    // Fast Android Networking
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'
    // Video Trimmer
    compile 'life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0'
    // Yoyo Animation
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    // Media Picker To Pick Photos And Videos Up
    implementation project(':mediapicker')
}
```

**build.gradle Project :**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
    google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: project build successfully when i comment two lines compile `com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used [link](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/getting-started/library-project-setup/) To Download And Import SDK Locally

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shod add maven to PROJECT LEVEL GRADLE file :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: maven project level addedm License defined into manifest, still not works

Comment: It has nothing to do with manifest. You should add those lines in Project gradle file (YourProject/build.gradle).  Did you add those lines ?

Comment: I've tested on my test project and there is no problem. I think the problem is hiding in a part of your project, that you didn't post.   I don't see your full project, but I see you are using flavors, maybe it is related to them.

Comment: flavor removed to test project, invalidate cache and restarted, but problem not solved !

Comment: Can you add more details, maybe full gradle files (2 of them) ?

Comment: Maybe it sounds silly, but do you have internet connection on the machine, where you are developing. Because your gradle error says that it can't connect to : http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/maven-metadata.xml